# Correct format of a query for C# visual studio

Tags: c#, sql

Can anyone help me correctly format my sql query for Visual Studio, I get an error by WITH it says Newline in constant.

Below is my code the code in short, it looks at a master sequence, counts it, if there is more then 1 the split_dlv will be updated with the value 1.

```
            SqlCommand cmdUpd2 = new SqlCommand(" WITH cte AS(
                                                + "SELECT master_seq"
                                                +  "FROM[ZS_CS_EVO_Integration].[dbo].[CS_Consolidation]"
                                                +  "where delivery_date = yesterday and[master_seq] <> 0"
                                                +   "GROUP BY master_seq"
                                                +  " HAVING count(master_seq) > 1 '" + yesterday + "'", IntConnect)
                                                + "UPDATE c"
                                                + "SET[split_dlv] = 1"
                                                + "FROM[dbo].[CS_Consolidation] c"
                                                + "INNER JOIN cte t"
                                                + "ON t.master_seq = c.master_seq and c.delivery_date = yesterday))";
```

Comment: Your first line is missing an ending quote. Read [ask] and try researching this error before asking a question.

Comment: You are missing a double quote in your first line

Comment: HAVING count(master_seq) > 1 '" + yesterday + "'", IntConnect) also look something missing

Answer (score 1):

May be your error because **you missing ; before With** statement, **it should be like ;with**

Better to use **StringBuilder** instead of string append.StringBuilder occupy less memory then string because it initialize object once, while string occupy memory for each append operation and hence use more memory.

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(";WITH cte AS(");
sb.Append(" SELECT master_seq");
sb.Append(" FROM[ZS_CS_EVO_Integration].[dbo].[CS_Consolidation]");
sb.Append(" where delivery_date = yesterday and[master_seq] <> 0");
sb.Append(" GROUP BY master_seq");
sb.Append(" HAVING count(master_seq) > 1 '" + yesterday + "'");
sb.Append(" , IntConnect)");
sb.Append(" UPDATE c");
sb.Append(" SET[split_dlv] = 1");
sb.Append(" FROM[dbo].[CS_Consolidation] c");
sb.Append(" INNER JOIN cte t");
sb.Append(" ON t.master_seq = c.master_seq and c.delivery_date = yesterday))");

SqlCommand cmdUpd2 = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString());
```

**Note :** I am still not clear with use of **sb.Append(" , IntConnect)");** in query, please update it and then try

Answer (score 0):

Why mess up with a lot of query in your code just put the sql code under a View or a Procedure then execute the view or procedure in your sql command.

But note that for a procedure the command will be

command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

this will reduce all the messup

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `@` symbol before your string so then it can span multiple lines. Then you don't need to have `+ "yoda yoda"` everywhere

And if you need to inject variables into it then you can just wrap the whole thing in `string.Format`